# ipython dataframe plotting setting color parameter?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, ipython

I am trying to plot using `pandas` `DataFrame` directly as the index column will automatically change to x-axis.

However, I really don't know how to set the color condition using `DataFrame`. i.e

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(b-z,index=frame1.index,columns=['delta'])
colors = np.where(df1.delta>0,'g','r')
df1.plot(ax=axes[0],marker='o',color=colors)
```

I don't know how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

what is `b`? what is `z`? from the sounds of of things you need to make two calls to `plot`.

```
df1[df1.delta > 0].plot(ax=axes[0], marker='o', color='g')
df1[df1.delta <= 0].plot(ax=axes[0], marker='o', color='r')
```

Comment: thx for help. b-z's just an array. this way works, yet could u improve it ? there's lines connecting each dot of the same color. but the there's no lines between red dots and green dots which is not what I expected. as the whole df1 share the same index, I want each dot being connected. And the tricky part is I want each dot being connected order by the Date(which is the index).But

Comment: df1[df1.delta > 0] and df1[df1.delta <= 0] have totally different index so it's difficult to combine them . Tha't why I at first want to do it in one line .

Comment: @XunBao could you post a complete and runnable example so that I can copy and paste your code and modify it directly?